# Rotating-schedule calendar

Tags: ms-project

I'm new both to MS Project and this kind of forum. I've searched for this question and I haven't found it, so sorry if it has been already asked.

I'm trying to make new resources calendars, but they work in a variable schedule (in a cycle of 6 weeks, which means that every week from 1 to 6 is different, and the 7th week is the same as the 1st, etc...). If I try to put exceptions, the program registers an incompatibility between them, so I have to change it day by day. Is there a way to make this more simple?

Comment: Calendar exceptions can be made using VBA which would simplify the process greatly. Unfortunately, Project will not allow "overlapping exception intervals" so doing each week rather than using a recurring exception may be the only way to go.

Comment: One thing to consider would be that if each day has the same number of working hours and your tasks are generally a day or longer, you could ignore the time-component. For example, if during week two the resources work 10-6, but the calendar is 8-4, mentally adjust to add 2 hours (e.g. task finish actually finishes at 6:00 PM instead of 4:00 PM as shown in the schedule). In other words, the schedule times don't have to be exact, the schedule is more about the flow of tasks and the relationships between them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA solution to create a calendar with a cycle of 6 rotating weekly schedules where each week has a different start and end time; all working days have a single 8-hour shifts.

```
Sub CreateRotatingCalendar()

    ' Create a calendar with a cycle of 6 rotating weekly schedules by
    '  utilizing the calendar exceptions.

    Const CalName As String = "6 Week Rotating"
    Const ExceptionName As String = "Cycle "

    Const Week1Start As Date = #7:00:00 AM#
    Const Week2Start As Date = #8:00:00 AM#
    Const Week3Start As Date = #9:00:00 AM#
    Const Week4Start As Date = #10:00:00 AM#
    Const Week5Start As Date = #11:00:00 AM#
    Const Week6Start As Date = #12:00:00 PM#

    Const CyclesStart As Date = #3/4/2019#    ' must be a Monday
    Const CyclesEnd As Date = #12/31/2024#

    ' create calendar, but ignore errors in case calendar already exists
    On Error Resume Next
    BaseCalendarCreate Name:=CalName, FromName:="Standard"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Dim c As Calendar
    Set c = ActiveProject.BaseCalendars(CalName)

    ' in case this routine is run again to update the rotating calendar,
    '  delete exceptions related to the rotation (and leave holidays)
    Dim e As Exception
    For Each e In c.Exceptions
        If e.Name Like ExceptionName & "*" Then
            e.Delete
        End If
    Next e

    ' remove other shifts and make Shift1 8 hours
    Dim wd As PjWeekday
    For wd = pjMonday To pjFriday
        c.WeekDays(wd).Shift1.Start = #8:00:00 AM#
        c.WeekDays(wd).Shift1.Finish = #5:00:00 PM#
        c.WeekDays(wd).Shift2.Clear
        c.WeekDays(wd).Shift3.Clear
        c.WeekDays(wd).Shift4.Clear
        c.WeekDays(wd).Shift5.Clear
    Next wd

    ' create the exceptions week by week
    Dim NumWeeks As Long
    NumWeeks = (CyclesEnd - CyclesStart) \ 7
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CycleNum As String
    Dim StartTime As Date
    For i = 1 To NumWeeks + 1
        Select Case i Mod 6
            Case Is = 1: StartTime = Week1Start: CycleNum = "1"
            Case Is = 2: StartTime = Week2Start: CycleNum = "2"
            Case Is = 3: StartTime = Week3Start: CycleNum = "3"
            Case Is = 4: StartTime = Week4Start: CycleNum = "4"
            Case Is = 5: StartTime = Week5Start: CycleNum = "5"
            Case Is = 0: StartTime = Week6Start: CycleNum = "6"
            Case Else
        End Select
        On Error Resume Next
        Set e = c.Exceptions.Add(Type:=pjDaily _
                                , Start:=CyclesStart + (i - 1) * 7 _
                                , Occurrences:=5 _
                                , Name:=ExceptionName & CycleNum)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            e.Shift1.Start = StartTime
            e.Shift1.Finish = StartTime + #8:00:00 AM#
        Else
            ' switch to day-by-day to not overwrite holidays inherited
            '  from the Standard calendar
            Dim d As Long
            For d = 1 To 5
                Set e = c.Exceptions.Add(Type:=pjDaily _
                                        , Start:=CyclesStart + (i - 1) * 7 + d - 1 _
                                        , Occurrences:=1 _
                                        , Name:=ExceptionName & CycleNum & " day " & d)
                e.Shift1.Start = StartTime
                e.Shift1.Finish = StartTime + #8:00:00 AM#
            Next d
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i

End Sub
```